# Vim Ag Plugin Context Option and Show Results in Tab

Tags: vim, grep, ag

I am using Gvim with `Ag.vim` plugin for search. I am trying to use options for `--before 4` and `--after 4` to get the context of the code. It returns the results in quickfix window as a single line. How to show the before and after code for a search pattern?

Here is my search pattern and path.

> :Ag -i --after 4 --before 4 pattern /search/path/

Is there a way to show the results in buffer or a tab rather than quickfix window?

I added this in my vimrc but it still shows the results in quickfix window.

> let g:ag_lhandler="topleft lopen"

Thanks.

Comment: You can use a redir command. First `:redir a`, then perform your operations and then type `:redir END`. Now the content will be in register a. You can create a new buffer by typing `:bnew filename` and then get into insert mode and then press Ctrl and R , and then press `a`. Your content will be pasted. If you want a function/command for this, I will do :)

Comment: Thanks @SibiCoder. There are too many steps for such functionality. Shouldn't Ag's options work as indented in Vim plugin?

Comment: You can use the plugin's issue tracker https://github.com/rking/ag.vim . Once you find the solution you can add as an answer. (I can create a function or command for your execpted workflow but dont know `Ag`.)

Comment: Use the [CtrlSF](https://github.com/dyng/ctrlsf.vim) plugin instead of Ag.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Just came across `CtrlSF` plugin. It does all that I requested here. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the requirements of my question can be fulfilled by a Vim plugin called `CtrlSF` [(CtrlSF Vim Plugin)](https://github.com/dyng/ctrlsf.vim) Thanks to @SatoKatsura for the recommendation.